# Get font from resources has bug in Java - Android

Tags: java, android, fonts, resources, typeface

I write code and use CompatResources to get font and set as TypeFace to views bug Fabric.io reported some crashes about it .

> Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException Font
>   resource ID #0x7f090000 could not be retrieved.

and it is my code :

```
tfFontIcon = ResourcesCompat.getFont(mContext, R.font.font_icon);
```

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try below soultion

**Solution 1**

Add your font in **assets** folders like below image

[image]

And use below method to set font typeFace

```
CommonUtils.setFont(context, binding.txtDigital, "Montserrat-Bold.ttf");

public static void setFont(Context context, TextView textView, String fontPath) {
    Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getResources().getAssets(), fontPath);
    textView.setTypeface(t);
}
```

**Solution 2**

Add font folder inside **res** folder like below image

[image]

And directly add **font family** into your textview

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_20ssp"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

I hope this can help you!

Thank You.

Comment: is there any way use resources not assets? what is the cause of crash?

Comment: i know xml or assets but problem in when set programmatically and use resources . view build in java and thats not solution

Comment: Can you add screenshot of where you add font file?